# Can't send mail to more than 100 recipients on Thunderbird, error : Ratelimit "spambombing_limit" exceeded appears

Tags: email, thunderbird, rate-limits

I have the following problem : I cannot send mails to more than 100 recipients, I get the following message if I try :

***Failed to send message.
An error occurred while sending mail. The server replied: Ratelimit "spambombing_limit" exceeded. Please check the message and try again.***

It worked fine a few days ago, same for my coworkers. It works for my colleague, he has the exact same configuration as mine.
Sending to a group doesn't work either.

Our version of Thunderbird is updated, Windows 10 is updated.
Something has changed but I can't find what.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"The server replied:...". You've most likely exceeded a threshold that your ISP set on the server to limit the number of messages sent by a particular sender over a period of time. You (or your IT department) may be able to contact your ISP and have them raise the limit.

Comment: …or stop spamming...

Comment: If email provider has *groups*, e.g., GMail, then use a group to send one email to all correspondents. That *might* count as only one email... or not.